# Is it possible to find the geometric series sum formula using calculus?

Tags: calculus

We know that the sum of a geometric series is $a(1-k^n )/(1-k)$ where $a$ is the first term of the series, n is its length and $k$ is its ratio. Is there a way to find this formula using calculus concepts?
I was thinking about this problem, but got stuck on a dead end, because integrals are used on continuous functions, while this kind of sum is discrete. Is there a trick to overcome this?

Comment: It is just simple algebra. If you want you could formulate a differential equation the series-polynomial satisfies and then solve that..

Comment: Yeah, *why* do you want to use calculus to explain something that can be explained with simple algebra?

Comment: Because it's more fun @AdamRubinson

Comment: The obvious idea would be to let $f(x) = \frac{a(1-x^n)}{1-x}$ and Taylor expand this function around $0$, so it would look like $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$. It remains to be seen if the derivatives are easily evaluated at $0$, but if I'm not wrong this series is precisely equal to the geometric series formula (it will stop at $k=n$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ be the desired ratio and $b$ a constant to be determined.

Define a series $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots$ such that
$a_m = \displaystyle\int_{m-1}^m bk^x\,\mathrm dx$ for any integer $m$.
Then

$$
a_{m+1} = \int_m^{m+1} bk^x\,\mathrm dx
= \int_{m-1}^m bk^{x+1}\,\mathrm dx
= k \int_{m-1}^m bk^x\,\mathrm dx = ka_m.
$$
and therefore $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots$ is a geometric series.

To determine the constant $b$ so that $a_1 = a$ is the desired first term of the series,
note that
$$
a_1 = \int_0^1 bk^x\,\mathrm dx = \left[\frac{bk^x}{\ln k} \right]_0^1
= \frac{b}{\ln k}(k - 1).
$$

So in order to obtain a series with the desired first term, we can simply set
$$ b = \frac{a \ln k}{k - 1}. $$

Now observe that
$$
a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n
= \int_0^1 bk^x\,\mathrm dx + \int_1^2 bk^x\,\mathrm dx
   + \cdots + \int_{n-1}^n bk^x\,\mathrm dx
= \int_0^n bk^x\,\mathrm dx,
$$

so the sum of the first $n$ terms of the series is just
$$
\int_0^n bk^x\,\mathrm dx
= \left[\frac{bk^x}{\ln k} \right]_0^n
= \frac{b}{\ln k}(k^n - 1) = \frac{a(k^n - 1)}{k - 1}.
$$

---

A question you might ask, however, is how we know that
$\displaystyle\int k^x\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{k^x}{\ln k}$
if we have not yet found a formula to sum a geometric series.
I have not thought of an answer to that question!

Comment: Thank you! Actually, it is possible to find the integral of k^x using the [integration by substitution method](https://imgur.com/a/Wv3676z).

Comment: And we know that $\int e^u\,\mathrm du=e^u$ because ... ? I'm not saying it you can't solve the integral without the series, just that I've never seen it done in that order so I don't know what the proofs would be like or even if they're possible.